# Is it Ok to use a <fragment> tag inside a layout of a RecyclerView's ViewHolder?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

May question is whether a `RecyclerView`'s `ViewHolder`'s layout can have a `<fragment>` tag such as this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment 
        android:name="com.some.FragmentOne"
        android:id="@+id/somefragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a good idea.

you'd be better to use  a **ScrollView** around a **LinearLayout** that the fragments are loaded into. The fragments will be loaded slightly sooner than with a **RecyclerView**, but you won't have to fight all the recycling infrastructure that you're not taking advantage of.

The fragments are going to be loaded on top of each other because when you commit the transaction, you're not actually changing the view. You're telling the fragment manager, "Hey, when you get a chance can you hook up this fragment to this `ViewGroup` ID?" The fragment manager goes with the first instance of that view ID that it finds, and so they get loaded on top of each other.

You might be able to get around that by having different IDs for the different positions, but I wouldn't recommend it.